# ReactJS, event.currentTarget doesn't have the same behavior as Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering if something like `event.currentTarget` exists in ReactJS, the problem using `event.target` onclick is that I get the `childDiv` instead of the `parentDiv`.

*Vanilla Javascript example:*

```js
document.getElementById("parentDiv").onclick = function() {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.id); // or this.id
    console.log(event.target.id);
};
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv">Parent (click me)
    <div id="childDiv">Child (then click me)</div>   
</div>
```

*ReactJS, (inside a stateless function):*

```
...
const myFunction = (event) => {  
    event.stopPropagation(); // Doesn't make a difference.
    console.log(event.target); // Not trying to get the child element
    console.log(this); // 'this' is undefined
    console.log(event.currentTarget); // Gets the '#document' element
};
...
<div onClick={() => myFunction(event)}>...</div>
...
```

I'm sure there are multiple solutions for something this basic, I'm surprised I couldn't find a thread talking about this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you go through this? https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

Comment: You're comparing regular function to an arrow, there obviously will be a difference with `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are not actually passing the `event`, not sure if this is a typo but it should error.

This:

```
onClick={() => myFunction(event)}>...</div>
```

Should be written like this:

```
onClick={(event) => myFunction(event)}>...</div>
```

Second, you don't need to pass a new function, just pass the reference to the already existing function `myFunction`.

```
<div onClick={myFunction}>
```

As you can see in the following snippet the code runs as expected:

It will print:

```
<div>click me</div>
undefined
<div>click me</div>
```

Note that the second handler of the parent `div` is not triggered, this proofs that `event.stopPropagation()` is working.

As for why `this` is undefined is because you probably run the code in `strict mode` (or inside a module which by default is in `strict mode`) and react will run the handler for you, this is not a native DOM event buy synthetic.
So basically running a function like that:

```
myFunc()
```

Will set the `this` to window (or `undefined` in strict mode)

here is a chart i made, maybe it can help you
[image]

```js
function App() {
  const myFunction = event => {
    event.stopPropagation(); // works as expected
    console.log(event.target); // Gets <div>click me</div>
    console.log(this); // 'this' is undefined
    console.log(event.currentTarget); // Gets <div>click me</div>
  };
  const myFunc2 = e => {
    console.log("myFunc2");
  };
  return (
    <div onClick={myFunc2}>
      <div onClick={myFunction}>click me</div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```